# (Marklogic) vCARD RDF vocabulary

Tags: rdf, marklogic

The RDF vocabulary list at the end of this Marklogic page:
https://docs.marklogic.com/10.0/guide/semantics/intro
includes the deprecated Namespace
http://www.w3.org/2001/vcard-rdf/3.0
and the file at the end of the URI is not consistent with the W3C specification:
https://www.w3.org/TR/vcard-rdf/

Comment: Is there a question or issue, or are you just looking to report an issue with MarkLogic documentation that could be improved?

Comment: The doco needs to be updated.